# How to design good looking iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I think I have just about mastered the basics of iPhone programming and now I want to make my apps look better.

Every time I show my family/friends what I have done they think it looks a little "basic". I am inclined to agree

I know how to customise the table view but apart from that everything I make just looks a bit "appy". All the books I have just cover the basics. There's nothing in there that looks amazing.

I know this is a very vague question but I really need to make things look better.

Do I have to be good at art?

I have heard of people using custom designs in Quartz composer, is this how they do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with @Cody, good UI/UX is not art, art does have a place. Art does not take the place of a good UI but does add to it. Not to much art, art needs to be a background part of the app. Backgrounds, icons, button backgrounds, etc.

If you, like me, can not make the art part, hire an artist--if the revenue will support that.

Finally, an artist is not by nature a UX designer, these are usually two different types of people.

Comment: Sure, this is true. I might have overstated my answer a bit. You do need logos, graphics, icons, etc. And you do need to be a bit of an artist to create decent looking work in this department. Most programmers that I know are not really artists, including myself. The best solution is definitely to get someone else to do this for you. Either hire someone (if you can afford it), or take advantage of all the freely available art. There are some *awesome* icon libraries that are licensed under GPL, for example. But it is definitely worth explicit mention that this differs from UX.

Comment: For icons checkout [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/), all B&W, colorize as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Good iPhone apps do not look like "art". They look like the standard Apple apps included with the phone. The real "art" to UI design is following the standard conventions of your platform. It's unimportant if your application looks "basic"; the really important things are that it's *functional* and *easy to use*. This is something Apple gets right in a big way, and it pays off for them handsomely.

Study the apps on your phone to see how they do things, and then follow those patterns. User testing (even if it's just with your friends and family) is *exactly* the right thing to do. If your program is powerful and useful enough, they won't be concerned that it looks a little basic. In fact, that can be a real advantage. The more complicated something is, the harder it is for someone to pick up and figure out how to use it right out of the box. The average iPhone user doesn't have a very long attention span, and with as many apps as are available on the App Store, it's hard to blame them for not wasting much time.

Comment: +1 for sharing this great insight.